# Trouble with chef-solo "Missing Cookbooks"

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-solo

I am trying to run chef-solo, and I have the following configuration

```
/var/chef

├── cookbooks
│   ├── cc_db
│   │   ├── Berksfile
│   │   ├── Berksfile.lock
│   │   ├── chefignore
│   │   ├── metadata.rb
│   │   ├── recipes
│   │   │   └── default.rb
├── node.json
└── solo.rb
```

node.json

```
{
  "run_list": [ "recipe[cc_db]" ]
}
```

solo.rb

```
file_cache_path "/var/chef"
  cookbook_path "/var/chef/cookbooks"
  json_attribs "/var/chef/node.json"
```

metadata.rb

```
depends 'database', '~> 5.1.2'
depends 'mysql2_chef_gem', '~> 1.0'
```

I've gotten this to work in a kitchen-test environment, but I'm trying it now on a different server using chef-solo.

Whenever I run:
chef-solo -c solo.rb

I get:

```
resolving cookbooks for run list: ["cc_db"]

================================================================================
Error Resolving Cookbooks for Run List:
================================================================================

Missing Cookbooks:
------------------
No such cookbook: database

Expanded Run List:
------------------
* cc_db

Platform:
---------
x86_64-linux


Running handlers:
[2016-09-20T15:34:05-04:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
Running handlers complete
[2016-09-20T15:34:05-04:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 02 seconds
[2016-09-20T15:34:05-04:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/chef-stacktrace.out
[2016-09-20T15:34:05-04:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
[2016-09-20T15:34:05-04:00] ERROR: 412 "Precondition Failed"
[2016-09-20T15:34:05-04:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

I'm confused because the database cookbook seem to be installed with berks, but chef isn't picking it up.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks.
myles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chef doesn't directly integrate with Berkshelf, so `chef-solo` knows nothing about that. Normally you would use something like `knife-solo` which ties them together, but you could also do it manually. Run `berks vendor /path/to/a/folder` and then set that folder as the `cookbook_path`.

Comment: I've run `berks vendor [cookbook_path]`, but still the error occur. I wonder why does chef-solo couldn't find the cookbooks eventhough we already define the path in solo.rb??

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just going around the problem.

I set up a chef-server on a virtual host, and do some final level testing on that.  I created nodes, bootstrapped them, then ran chef-client on the node.

I also don't have a very large server configuration, so I just uploaded the cookbooks and dependent cookbooks by hands.  Which I'm pretty sure is why chef-zero was failing.  At some point in the future I will get Berkshelf working in conjunction with everything to help ease the cookbook dependency process.